# Grails Resources and Cache Manifest

Tags: html, grails, cache-manifest

the grails resources plugin is a great benefit, but now I encounter the following problem:

I would like to create an HTML5 offline application and need to create a cache manifest. For this, I have to specify the urls of all used static resources. From the documentation, I only see the option to use `<r:layoutResources/>` which does not fit with the HTML5 cache manifest.

There is another SO question aiming in this direction, but the answer does not really fit: [Grails Resources Plugin -- How to get generated urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436495/grails-resources-plugin-how-to-get-generated-urls)

and the plugin documentation was also not of much help to me (maybe I just didn't see it) http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/

**Update:** just to explain the problem a little bit more in depth:

The ressources plugin modifies the URL of ressources. One example is that it might bundle several files together into one. A reference to stylesheet `a.css` and `b.css` might be turned into a reference to `ab.css`. Now, if I reference `a.css` and `b.css` in my html file (through the resources plugin) and the cache manifest (without the resources plugin since I need the plain URLs), the cache manifest will tell the browser to cache `a.css` and `b.css` but the browser will be looking for `ab.css` since this is the file which is references (through the resources plugin) from within the html file...

Comment: So, what is the issue? Why can't you create a controller that serves up the required file and use the resource tag to generate the links to the resources?

Comment: see my update. I hope this explains the problem a little bit better... THe workaround is to avoid the resources plugin, but it would be great if I could use it...

Comment: Okay, so the issue is bundling and the resources plugin. That makes more sense now. I highly doubt you are going to be able to get around this without getting into the internals of the plugin and making some modifications or writing your own extension. :/

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Thanx for reminding me that we work with open source. I now took a look at the sources and I guess the easiest way will be not to use the resources plugin :-(

Comment: You're welcome. You are right the simplest way around this would be to not use the plugin but you would end up sacrificing a lot by doing that. You might want to reach out to Marc Palmer or Luke Daley on twitter and see if they can lend you some additional direction about how to head with the plugin.